# php - prestashop Class 'Product' not found

Tags: php, web-services, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm writing a webservice using php and I'm using prestashop webservice library  (https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop-webservice-lib) . this is my code :

```
    define('DEBUG', true);
define('PS_SHOP_PATH', 'http://xxxxx.com/');
define('PS_WS_AUTH_KEY', 'xxxxx');
require_once ('PSWebServiceLibrary.php');

$webService = new PrestaShopWebservice(PS_SHOP_PATH, PS_WS_AUTH_KEY, DEBUG);
$xml = $webService->get(array('url' => PS_SHOP_PATH .'/api/customers?schema=synopsis'));

$customer = array();
$product = array();

/*if (strlen($_POST('c_email'))>0)
    $customer['email'] = Tools::getValue('c_email');
else
    $customer['email'] = 'admin@yoursite.com';
*/
$customer['email'] ="navid.abutorab@gmail.com";
$customer['firstname'] = "navid";
$customer['lastname'] ="abutorab";
$customer['address1'] = "adres";
$customer['city'] = "citye";
$customer['phone'] = "09360544841";

$id['country'] = '165';
$id['lang'] = '1';
$id['currency'] = '1';
$id['carrier'] = '3';

$product['quantity'] ="1";
$id_product="10104";
$product['id'] = $id_product;
echo Product::getPriceStatic($product['id']) . "-----";
$product['price'] = Product::getPriceStatic($product['id']);
$product['name'] = Product::getProductName($product['id']);

$product['total'] = $product['price'] * $product['quantity'];

$xml->customer->firstname = $customer['firstname'];
$xml->customer->lastname = $customer['lastname'];
$xml->customer->email = $customer['email'];
$xml->customer->newsletter = '1';
$xml->customer->optin = '1';
$xml->customer->active = '1';


$opt = array('resource' => 'customers');
$opt['postXml'] = $xml->asXML();
$xml = $webService->add($opt);



// ID of created customer
$id['customer'] = $xml->customer->id;
```

When I run the page , I get this error :

```
Class 'Product' not found in /home/xxxxx/public_html/test/test.php on line 37
```

line 37 is this line  :

```
$product['price'] = Product::getPriceStatic($product['id']);
```

what should I include to make it works fine ?

Comment: Are you developing a module? If you want to use the PrestaShop classes you have to 'working' in PrestaShop environment.

Comment: @sarcom , No I'm not developing for module , I'm working on an api for my application . I'm not very familiar with prestashop environment, How can I include these classes ?

Comment: You can't... You have to work with xmls and API calls

Comment: @sarcom I'm using the library and xml and api but the class is not working . Could you give me an example ?

Comment: You cannot use the Product class because you're not in the PrestaShop environment :). You have to make a new call to API to retrieve the product like an xml. E.g. `$product = $webService->get(array('resource' => 'product', 'id' => $id_product));`

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the following line in the starting of your web service code.

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../config/config.inc.php');
```

Note: Please adjust the path as per your file path. You just need to include the 'config.inc.php' file.